# Schema.org mandatory fields and the time needed until Google shows changes

Tags: seo, schema.org, google-rich-snippets

I have implemented Schema.org (using Microdata) inside my product pages and when I check Google Webmaster Tools it is crawled by Googlebot and interpreted successfully. The point is I have not implemented some properties inside `Product` type like `brand`.

I need to know whether there is some subset of all product attributes should be implemented essentially?

And the second question is how much it takes for Google to show product rating and price as rich snippet inside search results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are **no** mandatory properties/types in Schema.org.

However, consumers of the data, like Google Search, might have rules under which conditions they will make something with your data (e.g., they are looking for specific properties). So you’d have to check their documentation.

For Google Search, their Rich Snippets are documented at https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/. The [Products Rich Snippets](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/products) lists the required and optional properties/types. As you can see, the `brand` property is not required by Google for showing their Rich Snippet in the search results.

Answer (score 1):

Hussein 
As google has pointed out the structured data required for a snippet are :

Product
Name
Description
Pricespecifications (to include:)
Pricecurrency
Pricevalue
Availability
Validfrom
Image

First you should consider checking if the validfrom and availability attributes are added because both of them are the most common mistakes when you write your first SEO codes.

Then there are some attributes that while they are not in required list by Google's developers there seem to be the once that all successful snippets have (you might have noticed that too ) , the : review and vote attributes including the expect values from schema.org libraries. In some people's opinion ,mine also, having those will "almost" make sure they will get noticed.

Those are not pretty easy to get because u will have to create a way for getting reviews and votes.

Otherwise try using the webmaster new tool search console to highlight data for product snippet. Just make sure that the required attributes have their expected values in the text so you can mark all the above attributes with the tool.

Make sure all the attributes are markup and not meta data as it shows you are just making information up.
About the time , check that the structured data have increase for the peoduct and if not then fetch and submit to index.